# Laravel Update or Create Relationships

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have an Item model, that has ItemTranslations, I'm receive a Request with the Item I'm updating and the translations for that Item.

Now some of those translations will already be in the database (they have their own id), and some of them will be new. Is there a clean way to go about this?

**In pseudo: Update the Item with this request, for each Translations you find in this request, update the translation relation if it exists, else create it for this Item.**

This is the layout of my Item.

```
class Item extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['menu_id', 'parent_id', 'title', 'order', 'resource_link', 'html_class', 'is_blank'];

    public function translations()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(MenuItemTranslation::class, 'menu_item_id');
    }
}
```

This is the ItemTranslation

```
class ItemTranslation extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'item_translations';
    protected $fillable = ['menu_item_id', 'locale', 'name', 'order', 'description', 'link', 'is_online'];
}
```

Answer (score 14):

You could use the [`updateOrCreate`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#other-creation-methods) method on the `translations()` relationship. For example:

```
$item->translations()->updateOrCreate([
    'name' => $translation['name'],
    // Fields that should be used to find an existing record.
], [
    'description' => "New description",
    // Fields that should be updated.
]);
```

The **first** argument is the data that you want Eloquent to **look up** the `translation` by and **second** argument is the data that you want to be **updated**.

**Both** arguments will be used to **create** a new `translation` when an existing one couldn't be found.

Comment: I suppose this has to go in a foreach loop? to loop over the translations I'm receiving with the request? thank you.

Comment: There's a `createMany` (https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method) method, but it doesn't look like there's something like a `updateOrCreateMany` method.

Comment: @DelenaMalan May be you are searching for something like https://gist.github.com/tonila/26f6a82c4dbe63d93b22ac67eaee2d6d